# Deriving a formula for the moment of inertia of a pie slice of uniform density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, integration, moment-of-inertia

Say you have a right cylinder of radius $R$, and you take a pie slice of angle $\theta$ at the origin with mass $M$. How can you determine the moment of inertia?

My teacher says it is impossible to derive its moment of inertia given those two variables, but this problem was in our textbook.

Comment: MMOI about the center of mass or the geometry center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to a trivial integral, assuming that the relevant axis is the centre of the cylinder:
\begin{align}
I
& = \int_\Omega \rho\:r^2\:\mathrm dV
=\int_0^L\mathrm dz \int_0^\theta\mathrm d\varphi\int_0^Rr\mathrm dr \: \frac{M}{L\theta R^2/2}r^2
\\ & = \frac{2M}{R^2}\int_0^Rr^3\mathrm dr
\\ & = \frac12MR^2.
\end{align}
Note that it is independent of $\theta$ and $L$ (with the only dependence coming if you want to regard $\rho$ instead of $M$ as fixed), as it should be: the relationship between $I$ and $M$ is fixed by the radius of gyration, and this is only a function of the radial density profile.

Comment: You should also show that $$M = \int_{\Omega} \rho {\rm d}V$$

Comment: @ja72 Come again? Should I also show that $V=\int 1\mathrm dV$, or any more definitions? Or where does that "should" come from? (i.e. just to be clear: your comment is inappropriate in tone and content.)

Comment: Point taken. What I mean to say that to move from density to mass you need to use another integral. It may be obvious to you, but not to the _op_.

Comment: The OP is already pretty much out of line in terms of the level of this question with respect to the standards for this site (and indeed this answer already gives away rather more than I'm usually comfortable with on a borderline-homework question). If relating the mass and the density is beyond them then they need to spend more time with a calculus textbook, plain and simple. In any case, the steps *not* shown in this answer were intentionally chosen precisely *because* the OP should not have everything spoon-fed to them. If you think you can do better, submit an answer of your own.

Comment: Sorry if this was too "easy" for you - this site is the best site I could find and none of my friends had the answer :P

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the help. I showed my teacher and he meant that the problem didn't say the density was uniform, so it was "impossible." (!)

I assumed uniform density even though it wasn't in the problem itself.

Comment: @asdf : Your teacher seems to be wrong. You should make assumptions according to the context. If the book is discussing rigid bodies with uniform density, you should assume uniform density unless stated otherwise.

Comment: @asdf Sammy is right - unless the phrasing of the problem explicitly mentions a non-uniform density, it's a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the axis of rotation is the axis of symmetry of the cylinder, then the moment of inertia (MI) is the same as that of the cylinder which it came from, ie $\frac12 MR^2$ where $M$ is now the mass of the 'pie slice' rather than the mass of the 'whole pie' (= cylinder).

The explanation is the [Stretch Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stretch_rule), which says that the MI is the same if an object is stretched (or compressed) symmetrically along or around the axis of rotation. If every element of mass is kept at the same distance from the axis during any transformation, then there is no change in the MI.

Comment: Yeah, that stretch rule is a lot closer to the intuition I was hoping to convey. +1.

Comment: Thanks, he didn't teach us that (yet? I'm in AP Physics C).